# Natural Scrolling in Lubuntu 17.04

Tags: lubuntu

I've been trying to get natural scrolling running, but there is no option in the settings. I have looked at the parameters via synclient, and there is no option for natural scrolling there either, as in normal Ubuntu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You can try this. Notice 6 and 7 are swapped.

NaturalScrolling:

```
echo "pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12" > ~/.Xmodmap && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Information from:
https://andym3.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/the-one-line-method-of-getting-natural-scrolling-in-linux/

Comment: Much easier than other answers and no restart required. Works on 16.04. +1

Comment: this solution works!!

Comment: works in lubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 5):

As @Pilot6 suggested, make an edit to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf. But add to to BOTH the 'pointer' and 'touchpad' sections.

Find the 'pointer' section and add the "Natural Scrolling" option there.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"  # <-- add this line
EndSection
```

Do the same for the touchpad section:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "libinput"
    Option "NaturalScrolling" "true" # <-- add this line
EndSection
```

Save these changes, reboot, and natural scrolling should now work for you.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The listed solutions were only working for few applications on my Lenovo Z510. Add the following line to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics-conf under the first InputClass section:

```
Option "VertScrollDelta" "-90"
```

You can also test if this is working by executing the following command:

```
synclient VertScrollDelta=-90
```

However, the effect of the command vanishes after you log out. So it is preferable to edit the configuration file.

Source: https://diggle.tech/howto/2017/06/enable-natural-scroll-reverse-touchpad-on-lubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
```

and add

```
Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
```

to the end of the touchpad section of the file (before EndSection).

In Ubuntu 17.04 `libinput` is used. It does not have GUI settings yet.

Comment: I had to add that 'Option "Natural Scrolling" "true" ' to the pointer section, in order for it to work. ( I actually ended up adding it to both the pointer and touchpad sections.)

Comment: Only adding it to the end of the touchpad section didn't work for me in Lubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add a new configuration file for X11 libinput. The filename should start from `maximum counter + 1` to be proceeded the last.
For example, I have a bunch of files with default configurations:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 мар 20 15:02 10-amdgpu.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1350 апр 13 18:31 10-quirks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   92 мар 20 15:17 10-radeon.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  945 авг  1 11:28 40-libinput.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  590 мар  7  2017 51-synaptics-quirks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1751 мар  7  2017 70-synaptics.conf
```

So I added a new configuration file to the end of the list:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  113 авг  1 11:33 71-touchpad-scroll.conf
```

With the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for ubuntu 16.04 (If you have gnome desktop environment)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true
```