# lxde inverted mouse scroll

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, mouse, touchpad, lxde

I Just installed l-ubuntu, and installed LXDE on it. First of all I really love the LXDE due to its high performance. But what I don't liked that I am not able to do the natural mouse scrolling (inverted scrolling).

Can someone help me out
I used this line in my shell : `echo "pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12" > ~/.Xmodmap && xmodmap .Xmodmap`
But it's actually not working for me
Any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually use

```
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

to load the configuration.
If not at your home directory when executing

```
$ xmodmap .Xmodmap
```

you probably get

```
xmodmap:  unable to open file '.Xmodmap' for reading
xmodmap:  1 error encountered, aborting.
```

If that still doesn't solve the issue, [Natural Scrolling in Lubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908484/natural-scrolling-in-lubuntu-17-04) has several alternatives, which seem to have helped some.
A summary:

1. Modify `~/.Xmodmap` and reload it, as described above.
2. Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012071/226614), which includes both the pointer and touchpad.
3. If this does not work (100% of the times), try editing `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics-conf` as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1104581/226614).
4. Try changing `gsettings` with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll true` or `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false`. You can also do this via gui, with `dconf-editor` (may require installing it).

Comment: `Warning: Only changing the first 12 of 10 buttons.`
it's showing this error, afterwards nothing happens, Do I need to reboot it ?

Comment: @Shubharthak - That is not an error, but a warning, and it is ok. This should not require reboot. To be on the safe side, you could log out and back in.

Comment: Thank you so much man, The 3rd solution worked for me, Mad respect ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Under Keyboard and Mouse configuration there might also be the option "Natural Scrolling". If that's on then the wheel is inverted.